# WebAPI returning UnAuthorized if missing Header Value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, wcf-web-api

**Using APS.NET MVC 4 WebApi**

Each request must have a **Header** called "version" if it doesn't or the version is too low, I need to return an **UnAuthorized** value to the client. I'm not sure how to send that as a response .

In my **BaseApiController** I have this:

```
public abstract class BaseApiController : ApiController
{

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext controllerContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var versionText = controllerContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("version").FirstOrDefault();
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(versionText))
           int.TryParse(versionText, out _version);


        ***HERE*** If _version <1 then return UnAuthorized ???? ****  

        return base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's an acceptable way of doing it but you can try out returning a task that will just give you the response you want:

// if version < 1

```
return new Task<HttpResponseMessage>(() => 
       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
```